# How to use like active record for two columns simultaneously

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to make a search page which searches products under the  products database using their brands and models. But the problem here is that when a query contains both the brand and model number no results are returned because of the `like` and ``or_like` active records.

I am trying the following:

```
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("products");
    $this->db->like('brand', $query, 'both');
    $this->db->or_like('model', $query, 'both');
    $this->db->limit(3);
    $this->db->order_by("views", "ASC");
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

What should I do to get results for the queries that contains both the brand and model names?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the actual query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products 
  WHERE brand LIKE '%query%' 
    OR model LIKE '%query%' 
  ORDER BY views ASC
  LIMIT 3
```

That's the correct query to get records where `brand` contains 'query' or `model` contains 'query'.

I'd say to run `$this->db->last_query();` and see if the query is correct - then run that actual query against your database.